# Dynamic redirect url for PayPal Buy Now button

Tags: html, paypal, payment

I have integrated a PayPal Buy Now button on my site as follows:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="RECEIVER@RECEIVER.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="description here">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/NL/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Upon a succesfull purchase, I would like to redirect the user to a certain page (not known in advance - **dynamic**). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set "return" field in your form. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="URLspecificToThisTransaction">
```

For more information please visit the [documentation here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/)

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just one thing, sometimes it displays the old PayPal form (which does not redirect automatically). Any ideas how to force the new checkout form (which is also prettier)?

Comment: This link describe how to set the autoreturn https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside, hope it helps.